# How long should it take to a 1.5 tons AC to cool down a 2000sqf house from 80F to 77F?

Tags: hvac, cooling

I know that it might depend on a lot of things like:
-how air tight is the house
-how old it is (insulation, windows etc)
-what windows are installed -BTW I have casement window
-outdoor temp (currently 86F)

Please just give me a rough estimate or ask me more questions to narrow down the posibilities
The house is more like 1900 sqf actually and downstairs is colder... 75F

Here are the settings that I received from HomeDepot at my request 
This is a Trane XR16-018 (not sure about the last three digits)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

As written this question is pretty hard to answer.  It sounds like you're having AC problems tho and need a test method.

Find or purchase 2 probe type thermometers like thermometers. Analog or digital doesn't matter, the only things that are important are that they have a probe and that they give the same reading laying next to each other on a table (you will be surprised how many don't).  You can purchase these many places for under $10, there normally used in the kitchen.
[image: example of probe thermometer]

Take these to the area of your furnace and find someplace to stick each in, one in the return air, one in the supply air.  There is always a crack or hole in the ductwork somewhere, I have yet to see a case where a hole needed to be made.  On the return air side, the simple place is where the air filter is located. The supply side is harder to find sometimes, but just get the probe into the airflow.

Once the system has been running 15-20 minutes the thermometer should be reading temps about 15-20 degree's difference.

[image: example]

If your aren't getting 15-20 degrees of cooling you may need a service man, but check the filters first, and check airflow on the outside coils as well.  They typically need to be hosed off once or twice a year.

Comment: I already have this http://www.ebay.ca/itm/Mini-Digital-Handheld-Wind-Speed-Meter-Scale-Anemometer-Thermometer-LA-/252142170682?hash=item3ab4d8323a:g:BX8AAOSw~bFWLaP8  and I can tell you that at the supply registers I have like 17C and at the return registers I have like 25C at the return with the set temperature 80F (the damn AC thermostat is in Fahrenheit only) The furnace is brand new but probably slightly undersized (1.5 tons for 1900sqf, basement + main floor). The basement is really chilly but for the main floor in very hot days like today the AC has to work longer I guess

Comment: You may have a balancing problem then.  A service man can check air velocity at various registrars and make minor adjustments via dampers in the ductwork (different than register dampers) The fan speed may also be set to high or too low.  Was it professionally installed, if so the installer should have made these adjustments.

Comment: Yes it was, an Ontario Enbridge installer working for HomeDepot part time did the work, I have 10 years warranty parts and labour, I can call them back any time :-)
See the update of the initial post for more info and settings. I have not checked them

Comment: I'd call them back. Sounds like it needs some balancing.

Comment: No balancing possible, I have no supply and return dampers. It is a finished basement but as much as I can see there is nothing like that. They can probably be installed in the furnace room, where the return and the supply are visible and in reach

Comment: Looks like I had it set too low and the thermostat is on a hallway that ends into my office -lots of heat generated by my computer. and it is a south facing room. I adjusted the thermostat for 80 and now I can hear it going on and off like every 15-20 minutes and it stays on for a short time

Comment: A system with properly balance airflow should take all that into account.

Comment: As I said it can not be balanced unless dumpers are installed...

Comment: In my experience, it's not common for residential systems to be balanced. Most HVAC companies simply oversize the units, rather than installing dampers. Installing dampers increases the initial installation cost. Especially since manual dampers will likely not be used correctly by homeowners, and automatically controlled dampers are expensive.

Comment: @Tester101 I guess it depends who put it in and maintains it then.  In our house, and the house before this one, it's balanced and I watched it being done with an airflow meter, 2 guys and walking talkies.

Comment: @Tyson it depends on what people are willing to pay for.  In higher end markets, you can offer a bit better service.

Comment: @Tester101 the OP could still need a blower speed adjustment, it may be too low for AC.  Most blowers have separate speed settings for heat, cool and fan only, I guess that could vary by higher/lower end too tho

Comment: @Tyson I think most units come factory set with HIGH speed for COOL. Cheapo technicians leave it, better companies test, and set it where it is best.

Comment: Yeah I think this is the case. When on heating the furnace is OK but I could clearly hear more noise from the vents which means it has a highre speed for that. My problem right now is that the AC reaches the set temperature for the house but it does not seem to stop for lower temperatures.... If I have it set on 80F the AC cycles on and off every 10 minutes. I walk up with 77F and it is still running. I am temporarily collecting the water in a bucket and not much has been collected over night, so I am not sure if it run continuously over night