# In what circumstances would an AC produce no condensate but still cool the air?

Tags: hvac, cooling

In what circumstances would an AC produce no condensate but still cool the air?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My AC is set to 77F and the thermostat reaches that temperature but the AC keeps running. Why?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/91600/my-ac-is-set-to-77f-and-the-thermostat-reaches-that-temperature-but-the-ac-keeps)

Comment: This is basically the same question as your [previous one](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/91600/my-ac-is-set-to-77f-and-the-thermostat-reaches-that-temperature-but-the-ac-keeps). You should edit any new information into that question (e.g. does the unit produce no condensate?).

Comment: I think these two are different questions. It does not matter if the same problem made me ask two separate questions. By asking the above I would like to know if there are any circumstances under which an AC would produce no condense. It is a more general question. Ex: I suspect that if I reduce the RH of the air in a room to the maximum possible using a regular DH an AC would have no humidity to condense when it tries to cool that room. This has nothing to do with my other question where the thermostat seems to be the smoking gun

Comment: The body of the question doesn't seem to match the title.

Comment: You have a single, specific problem with multiple symptoms. Asking a question for each symptom isn't going to help you get good answers, nor will it help us build up knowledge on this site.

Comment: I edited the question. The only valid comment above was that of Tester101

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Condensate is a byproduct of air conditioning, which is created when moisture in the air condenses on the cold evaporator coils. There are two situations where an air conditioner would not generate condensate.

If there's no moisture in the air, then there's nothing to condense out of the air.

If the coils are not cold enough (below the dew point), the moisture will not condense out of the air.

Also note, that if the coils are too cold. The condensate will freeze, so it will not drain out until the coil defrosts.

Another note. If the drain does not have a trap,  it's possible that condensate will not drain until the fan shuts off.

Comment: So basically, when you do not have access to the coil, one way to check if your coil freezes is to let it freeze, disconnect the drain tubing from the drain and drain it into an empty bucket. Run the blower to speed up the ice melting and wait to see if water collects into your bucket.

Answer (score 1):

- Dew point below coil temperature.
- Plugged condensate drain.
- Coil temperature below freezing (0°C/32°F).

Answer (score 0):

Well ..one of the possible reasons is that the compressor lost refrigerant. I just realized that. My compressor was doing the job but not well enough. I was not experienced enough so I could say that the tin around the coils should have been a lot colder than it was and the house would eventually reach the set temperature but after some time which made me thing that everything was OK it was just the thermostat that was not getting it. One of the symptoms that was visible to me was "no more condense" hence my question

Comment: This community probably could have been more useful, if you would have described the problem you were having, instead of asking a series of vague questions.

Comment: Well I tried to collect info so I could use my own logic to isolate the problem. I provided enough information in the other threads. Sorry if that was not enough. I added some explanations above

Comment: When a system starts underperforming, the first thing a technician always checks is the refrigerant level.

Comment: I don't have the tools and I am not a technician ..but I will keep in mind for the future. For me, in the beginning it was not under performing , cooling wise, but it was malfuctioning, it was failing to stop..